# "transform: rotate()" causes unwanted "wagging" motion

Tags: css, spinner, css-animations

I was playing around with some `@keyframes` animations and i got this funky "wagging" kind of motion, problem is I don't know why...

```css
.spinner {
    position: relative;
    border: 16px solid #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: var(--size);
    width: var(--size);
    --size: 100px;
}

.spinner>* {
    position: absolute;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    border-top-color: var(--color);
    top: var(--distance); bottom: var(--distance);
    left: var(--distance); right: var(--distance);
}

.spinner>:nth-child(1) {
  --color: orangered;
  --distance: -16px;
  animation: spin1 1.8s ease-in-out infinite;
}
.spinner>:nth-child(2) {
  --color: skyblue;
  --distance: -8px;
  animation: spin2 1.8s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes spin1 {
    0% { 
      transform: rotate(0deg); 
    }
    25% {
      top: -16px; bottom: -16px;
      left: -16px; right: -16px;
    }
    50% {
      top: -8px; bottom: -8px;
      left: -8px; right: -8px;
    }
    75% {
      top: -16px; bottom: -16px;
      left: -16px; right: -16px;
    }
    100% { 
      transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes spin2 {
    0% { 
      transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
    25% {
      top: -8px; bottom: -8px;
      left: -8px; right: -8px;
    }
    50% {
      top: -16px; bottom: -16px;
      left: -16px; right: -16px;
    }
    75% {
      top: -8px; bottom: -8px;
      left: -8px; right: -8px;
    }
    100% { 
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I'm guessing the "wagging" is caused by the resizing of the 2 inner div:s, however I haven't been able to figure out how to get rid of it.. I'd appreciate both a solution and a better explanation as to why this happens so i can avoid it in the future.

**Never mind...** after capturing a gif of the animation I realized that the "wagging" was just an optical illusion caused by the way I animate the two slivers...
[image]

Comment: Is it intentional that the two spinners switch from inner/outer tracks at the 50% mark?

Comment: It looks like that because you have `ease-in-out` for the timing function. Change that to `linear` and it's no longer wobbly.

Comment: I think it only looks like its "wagging" because the inner and outer tracks switch places?

Comment: @Ben yes it is.

Comment: @MrLister yea... i realized that... turns out its just an optical illusion :)